# how to static image show in vue?

Tags: laravel, image, vue.js, static

in My Laravel project I use vue . In my vue component I want to show static image, but the image not showing

```
 <img style="border:10px solid #000;"  :src="'public/images/principle.jpg'" alt="">
```

Comment: image in public folder ? or in storage folder and what is url generated now can you put in question

Answer (score 2):

```
 <img style="border:10px solid #000;"  src="/images/principle.jpg" alt="">
```

Comment: you should put explain as well why you thing your code will work

Comment: is your image outside of the src folder?

Comment: my image location public ->  images ->principle.jpg

Comment: @TareqAhmed can you show what url is generated and what is 404

Comment: it totally blank in view page

Comment: what is you that page full url .?

Answer (score 1):

The error is because you are defining a string into a vue binding

```
:src=""
```

This expects a javascript constant

You could just do

```
src="/images/test.png"
```

But this will cause errors as you navigate to sub routes and pages.

In Laravel there is an asset helper and it looks like this

```
asset('images/test.png')
```

This will output a full url

```
http://localhost:8000/images/test.png
```

This asset helper is useful in PHP. But is not available to JS

So you can make it available using a vue mixin

In the head section of your HTML

Add this

```
<script> window._asset = '{{ asset('') }}'; </script>
```

This will bind the asset helper to the window

Next create a mixin in your app/js

It will look something like this

```
module.exports = {
    methods: {
        asset(path) {
            var base_path = window._asset || '';
            return base_path + path;
        }
    }
}
```

The final step is to require the mixin

in your app.js

```
Vue.mixin(require('./asset'));
```

Then you can use it in vue

```
<img :src="asset('images/test.png')" />
```